# Multi-Threading Issue in Jmeter with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

We're trying to use Jmeter and Selenium for performance testing. When we run scripts with one thread, the execution succeeds; however, if we run the scripts with five threads, two or three of the threads fail every time

We tried with reducing the ramp-up time and made use of the Selenium Grid feature.yet having the same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your "fail" statement doesn't tell the full story, you need to share at least response message and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) contents so we could understand what's going on. Check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) article.

Also it's not very clear how do you integrate JMeter with Selenium. If you use some custom Groovy code in [JSR223 Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) - make sure that it's [thread-safe](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety) and you're not re-using the same WebDriver instance by multiple threads.

Also be aware of [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler) plugin which provides JMeter integration with Selenium and it's suitable for multi-threaded execution.

And last but not the least, using real browsers for load testing is not recommended by either [Selenium developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

> Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

or [WebDriver Sampler developers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial)

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

You should be using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request%3E) < samplers to create the main load ([make sure to configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)) and i.e. 1 instance of WebDriver for checking the frontend performance.